# How to pass code behind variable via hyperlinkfield

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

This is my code behind in C# .

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Name = "Nitin";                      
    }
```

I have a GridView in which there is a Hyperlinkfield.I want to send `Name` from C# page(one in code behind) to next page via HyperLinkField but it is not one of the BoundField's of the GridView(i.e. Which I get from EntityDataSource). This is my asp.net code.

**code**:

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="WorkItemsEntityDataSource">
    <Columns>
        <asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="Id"                    
                datanavigateurlfields="Id"
                datanavigateurlformatstring="~\WorkItems.aspx?Id={0}"          
                headertext="Id"/> 
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TFSId" HeaderText="TFSId" SortExpression="TFSId" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsBillable" HeaderText="IsBillable" SortExpression="IsBillable" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: post your grid view code and elaborate ur problem clearly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass navigation URL from code behind also like this

In Aspx Page

```
              <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyp" runat="server" Text="Navigation"></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

In Code behind User grid view data bound event like this

```
protected void grddata_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {    
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            int ID = Convert.Int32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID"));
            HyperLink hyp = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hyp");
            hyp.NavigateUrl = "Test.aspx?Name='" + Request.QueryString["test"] + "'&&ID"+ ID +"";
        }
    }
```

i think this will help you...

Comment: Hi Rajpurohit ,I am wondering how to send Id from bound field of GridView with Name also via HyperLinkField.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about using it in a data-bound control actually, but the url you are building definitely doesn't contain the QueryString parameter 'Name'. It should look like this:

```
~\WorkItems.aspx?Id={0}&Name={1}
```

of just replace the Id with Name if Id is not needed:

```
~\WorkItems.aspx?Name={0}
```

as for substitution - I don't know what properties does your data-object have and how to bind to them. I think you have no problem with it since binding to Id works (probably).

**UPDATE**

If Name is not returning from datasource, you should either create new entity which contains Name field as well, or use some constant name, like you are declaring in a page (not sure it this same name should be shown in every row).
The second option can be implemented like this:

```
~\WorkItems.aspx?Id={0}&Name=<%= Name %>
```

Comment: Actually Name in not the one which I am getting from EntityDataSource thats the code behind variable .So, you know how to send that please reply.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Posted an update about embedding server-variable into ASP page

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="test">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="temp" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~\WorkItems.aspx?Id={0}&Name={1}",  Eval("Name"), Name)%>' ></asp:HyperLink>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a `HyperLinkField`'s url by doing this:

```
protected void pendingAccountsGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((HyperLink) e.Row.Cell[0].Controls[0]).NavigateUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    }
}
```

Just change it to specify the correct index in `e.Row.Cell[0]`.